# Default parameters are injected as object in babeljs/reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

My reactjs setup with babeljs is show below

[image]

My action.js

```
export function onIncrement() {
  return {
    type: 'INCREMENT'
  };
}

export function onDecrement() {
  return {
    type: 'DECREMENT'
  };
}
```

container/App.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as CounterActions from '../actions';

    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        const { counter, actions } = this.props;
        return (
          <div>
            <p>
              Clicked: {counter} times
            </p>
            <p>
              <button onClick={actions.onIncrement}>
                +
              </button>
            </p>
            <p>
              <button onClick={actions.onDecrement}>
                -
              </button>
            </p>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    App.propTypes = {
      counter: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    function mapStateToProps(count) {
      return {
        counter: count
      };
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(CounterActions, dispatch)
      };
    }

    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps
    )(App);
```

containers/root.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import App from './App';

export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    const { store } = this.props;
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

Reducer/index.js

```
export default function counter(count = 0, action) {
  console.log(count)  // this comes as object {}
  console.log(action) // initially it as { type: '@@INIT'}
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return count + 1;
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return count - 1;
    default:
      return count;
  }
}
```

store/configureStore.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer from '../reducers';

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}) {
  // thunkMiddleware to handle async actions in redux
  const middlewares = [thunkMiddleware];
  // chrome devtool extension
  let devtool;

  if (NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // redux-logger to log the redux state events in window.console
    const logger = createLogger({
      duration: true
    });
    middlewares.push(logger);

    // devtools - redux-chrome extension
    devtool = window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : undefined;
  }
  // store - combines reducers and enchancements to redux using middlewares
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    devtool,
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
  );
  // hot module replacement for only for reducers
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      // default - as es6 to es5 transpile in babel make the module to export as
      // module.export = somemodule.default
      const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers').default;
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
  }
  return store;
}
```

my main.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import Root from './containers/Root';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';

const initialState = window.__INITIAL_STATE__;

const store = configureStore(initialState);

render(
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My Package.json

[image: my package.json]

& i am using webpack for bundling and babel for transpiling.

When i initially run this application on i get this error below,

[image: Error]

Further investigate this issue, i found the transpiled code as show below

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = counter;
function counter() {
  var count = arguments.length <= 0 || arguments[0] === undefined ? 0 : arguments[0];
  var action = arguments[1];

  console.log(count, "count"); // this comes as object {}
  console.log(action, "action"); // initially it as { type: '@@INIT'}
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return count + 1;
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return count - 1;
    default:
      return count;
  }
}
```

My Question is:

1. Why my defualt parameter is injected as Object {} ?
2. Is this babel problem ?
3. Am i doing anything wrong here?

The above code only works, when i change this to below,

```
export default function counter(count = 0, action) {
  console.log(count , "count")  // this comes as object {}
  console.log(action, "action") // initially it as { type: '@@INIT'}
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return count + 1;
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return count - 1;
    default:
      return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `configureStore` function:

```
export default function configureStore(initialState = {}) {
  // ...
}
```

You setting `initialState` to `{}`, so if `window.__INITIAL_STATE__` is `undefined` you will get `{}` as initial state of your reducer.
Try to change this to:

```
export default function configureStore(initialState = 0) {
  // ...
}
```

There is no problems with babel output.

Answer (score 0):

future:

That empty object injection is due to i am setting the initialState to = {} in configureStore.js, i changed that to undefined, it worked like a charm

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer from '../reducers';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  // thunkMiddleware to handle async actions in redux
  const middlewares = [thunkMiddleware];
  // chrome devtool extension
  let devtool;

  if (NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // redux-logger to log the redux state events in window.console
    const logger = createLogger({
      duration: true
    });
    middlewares.push(logger);

    // devtools - redux-chrome extension
    devtool = window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : undefined;
  }
  // store - combines reducers and enchancements to redux using middlewares
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    devtool,
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
  );
  // hot module replacement for only for reducers
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      // default - as es6 to es5 transpile in babel make the module to export as
      // module.export = somemodule.default
      const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers').default;
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
  }
  return store;
}
```

For more details:
https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1502#issuecomment-194151490

Answer (score -1):

In your `mapStateToProps` function, you first need to extract `count` from Redux state like this :

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    counter: state.count
  };
}
```

Comment: I am not near my computer now. Anyway how is this possible ? What is the use of taking state.count ? I think this won't work. in my code if you print count in mapStateToProps it will show you as Object {}, how come this state,count will work ? Care to explain please?

Comment: Hi, this is not working... I am getting undefined while i put console.log(state.count)

Comment: Please, read the doc from react-redux instead of downvoting me.. This may not be the main error but I think you're misunderstanding how to listen to Redux store updates : https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments in `mapStateToProps(count)` you're dealing with the entire redux store, not just the `count` value you're expecting.

Comment: Have you seen my answer which was posted above ?. What you are saying is right when I am using combineReducer method to combine the multiple reducers. This is a single reducer and I am not using combine reducer as shown the code above. i think you need to also read the docs once again :) .